# WatchKit Can not set the Label title

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacelabel

I have tried to set the WKInterfaceLabel title programmatically but, It is not changing.

```
WKInterfaceLabel *titleLabel;
```

Couldn't set the title by using this,

```
[titleLabel setText:str];
```

Also tried Attributed string too,

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str];
[titleLabel setAttributedTitle:attString];
```

Comment: When and where do you create `titleLabel` and add it to the interface?

Comment: @jrturton: drag and drop  outlet into InterfaceController from the storyboard.

Comment: Ok, and when are you setting the text? Interface updates are ignored if the controller isn't active.

Comment: I am setting the text on a Button Action.